# Is there a way to resize content in a responsive div?

Tags: html, css

I have tried searching high and low for this answer and I'm not sure if I'm phrasing it incorrectly or what, because I haven't had much luck!

So I have this little paragraph here that I would like to keep centered and small, like so:

[a partial image of a webpage, showing navigation and a small section of text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qd7Y.png)

Here's how I've been writing it:

```css
.intro {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid intro">
  <hr style="height: 5px; width:40%;">
  <h2>Hi, I'm Heather!</h2>
  <h4>I'm a graphic design student out of New Hampshire with a love for all things fun, colorful, and creative!</h4>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="resume.pdf">Resume</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:heather@hlcstudios.com">Email</a></p>
  <hr style="height: 5px; width:40%">
</div>
```

This is obviously a problem because when I size the browser down, it still takes up 25% of the screen so it looks like this:

[an image of a sized down version of the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYAkW.png)

I know there is a way to make it responsive and still keep the text centered without taking up the whole div because I've seen it done, I just can't seem to figure out how to do it myself.

Thanks so much in advance and I really hope this question makes sense! :)

Comment: You can try giving a fixed max-width too like this https://jsbin.com/ceviyoyopu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: That worked for the text, but ended up cutting off my links when I resized the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

when setting `max-width` it means it will only reach the maximum width of this and won't allow anymore. So when you resize your screen it will become smaller and smaller.

Maybe try using `min-width` when trying to make a menu responsive:

```
.intro @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 25%;
  }
}
.intro {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm hoping to avoid using max-width for that reason, I don't really want people to have to squint to read things lol.

The min-width didn't do anything for me, unfortunately. But thanks for the help anyway :)